# iOS 7 : set an image(for background image or a View) dynamically during runtime?

Tags: ios

I have an app for different clients, the clients need to have their own logos and different background colors for the same app(of course a lot more customization for each client required). Every week or so I get a request to deploy for a new client and with their new logos/images. I was thinking to have a deployer app that with passing an iD of a client, I would be able to download all their logos/images from the server(as I have them ready there) and inject them to the same generic app that I have to make it easier to deploy for a new client. My app is a web based app that I get most of my data from server. I know that the bundle is readonly and I don't want to keep all the possible images/logos in one app either and I don't want to make this manually as much as possible(I'm doing right now). I thought it could be easier approach that can reduce my manual customization process with using web service calls for downloading dynamic data and replace those images/logos from server to my app.
Any thought?
TIA,

Comment: Seb, so even after delivery the generic app to the client, for the first time they have to download logos/images to /lib and use them from there right? in this case every time you switch to different screens where I want to use client's image/logo instead of default(generic) ones , the swapping images makes a quick flash. would anything I can do to prevent this (flash)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually something very simple to do.

1. Request your new data from your web service
2. Get the URL of your new image/logo
3. Use NSURLSession or AFNetworking to request that file
4. Keep the image in a cache so you won't have to re-download the same file twice

I hope it answers your question.

edit: @weiyin gave you the cache part of my solution

Comment: Seb, so even after delivery of the generic app wired with appropriate web service call for the client, for the first time they have to download logos/images to /lib right? in this case every time you switch to different screens, after each login(with having the images ready in /Lib) where I want to use client's image/logo instead of default(generic) ones , the swapping images makes a quick flash. would anything I can do to prevent this (flash)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. Download the files somewhere into the app's library directory. To get the library directory:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *library = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
```

Then use `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:...]` to create the image object. Pass the `UIImage` to your `UIImageView`.